# Cannot use android.contacts.SORT_ORDER on android 6.0

Tags: android, xamarin, contacts, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm trying to get the contacts sort preferences but on android 6.0 i'm getting and exception SettingsNotFoundException when using "android.contacts.SORT_ORDER".

Is there a specific value to use to get the contacts sort preferences?

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: int sort_order=Settings.system.getInt (getApplicationContext ().getContentResolver (),"android.contacts.SORT_ORDER");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=217048&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Sta&start=500).

This "android.contacts.SORT_ORDER" has been removed since API 21.

> Is there a specific value to use to get the contacts sort preferences?

So, no, there is no such value now, we need to save it by our self.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I didn't find any documentation related to this issue.